# Landscape and Portrate View in iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Now, in my iPad application there is two orientation req. but both are so much different means it`s difficult to manage on autoShouldrotate  so we can take different xib. for that. For that how to manage This both view.

If any one have references books or sites than send to me.

Thanks.
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this by have a view controller which has two child views, one for each orientation (and each one controlled by it's own view controller). On the didRotateFrom... methods etc, you can fade / swap between the two views. Quite simple.

Comment: have any example for such application. or each time we have to add new view in application current view ?

Comment: Have you any tutorial links about this ?